# How to add a repeated form in a loop symfony2 for the same entity

Tags: php, forms, loops, symfony, formbuilder

I want to build a questionnaire form.
When I use the following code, I can only see the last question of my table that contains 18 questions (and the answer field).

I can't use a collection because my questionnaire is going to be more complicated, some questions with multiple answers, some others in true/false, etc. I simplified the code to fix this problem first.

```
    //Get question array collection
    $questions = $questionnaire->getQuestions();
    $formBuilderQuestionnaire = $this->createFormBuilder();

    //Make a loop for each question
    foreach($questions as $question)
    {
        //Create an answer form
        $answer = new Answers($question, $evaluation);
        $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($answer);

        //Add a answer text box with the question as label
        $formBuilder->add('answerText', 'textarea',  array(
        'required' => false,
        'label' => $question->getQuestionText()
        ));

        $formBuilderQuestionnaire->add($formBuilder);

    }

    //Create the form
    $form = $formBuilderQuestionnaire->getForm();
    return $form->createView();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you are creating a new formbuilder on each iteration of the loop ... ? should you be doing this ?

Comment: My question is : how to make all the questions (of the database) appear in the view ? Because now only the last question appears.

Comment: I create a form builder for each answer because I want to create a line in the database for each answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to a friend.
I had to replace the createformBuilder

```
   public function generateForm($questionnaire, $evaluation)
{

    //Get question array collection
    $questions = $questionnaire->getQuestions();
    $formBuilderQuestionnaire = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $i = 0;


    //Make a loop for each question
    foreach($questions as $question)
    {

        //Create an answer form
        $answer = new Answers($question, $evaluation);
        $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($i, 'form', $answer);


        //Add a answer text box with the question as label
        $formBuilder->add('answerText' , 'textarea',  array(
            'required' => false,
            'label' => $question->getQuestionText() 
        ));

        $formBuilderQuestionnaire->add($formBuilder);

        $i++;

    }

    //Create the form
    $form = $formBuilderQuestionnaire->getForm();
    return $form; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility: Add an iterator to your form elements:

```
//controller
$idx = 1;
foreach ($list as $elem) {
  $formBuilder->add('checkbox'.$idx,CheckboxType::class, ['label' => $elem->getName() ]);
  $idx++;
}
```

Then it will iterate automatically in the twig:

```
//output.html.twig
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

When you define your own form theme you are able to address the form variables like:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block date_widget %}
  {{ form.vars.value }} 
{% endblock %}
```