# Symfony3 createFormBuilder with loop of 'add'

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to loop on the add of a custom form in Symfony 3, like:

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
$profilForm = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('Nom', TextType::class);
    ->add('Description', TextType::class)

foreach ($variable as $key => $value)
{
    $profilForm
        ->add('Widget', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Créer' => 'C',
            'Afficher' => 'R',
            'Modifier' => 'U',
            'Supprimer' => 'D'),
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true))
}
$profilForm
    ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

The problem is that I get the error :

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createView" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder".

Also if I do like this:

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
$profilForm = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('Nom', TextType::class);
    ->add('Description', TextType::class)

foreach ($variable as $key => $value)
{
    $profilForm = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('Widget', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Créer' => 'C',
            'Afficher' => 'R',
            'Modifier' => 'U',
            'Supprimer' => 'D'),
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true))
}
$profilForm
    ->add('send', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

It overwrite the previous entries.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this:

```
$tmpForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('Nom', TextType::class)
    ->add('Description', TextType::class);

$i = 2;
foreach ($listWidget as $key => $widget)
{
    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $widget->getNom());
    $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($i++, FormType::class, null); 
    $formBuilder
        ->add($widget->getNom(), ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Créer' => 'C',
            'Afficher' => 'R',
            'Modifier' => 'U',
            'Supprimer' => 'D'),
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true));
    $testForm->add($formBuilder);
}
$tmpForm->add('send', SubmitType::class);
$profilForm = $tmpForm->getForm();
```

Thanks to this post: [How to add a repeated form in a loop symfony2 for the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440145/how-to-add-a-repeated-form-in-a-loop-symfony2-for-the-same-entity)

Answer (score -2):

I have this solution that's cleaner for a foreach on a "-add."

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder();
        foreach ($activites as $activite){
            $form = $form
                ->add($activite->getID(). '_isOk', CheckboxType::class)
                ->add($activite->getID(). '_commentaire', CheckboxType::class);
        }
        $form = $form->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        return $this->render('fiche_proprete/new.html.twig',[
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
```