# Same field multiple times Symfony 4 form

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, repeat

I have an Entity **Report**, which is holds many **Answers**.

```
class Report
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="report")
     */
     private $answers; 
     ...
}

class Answer
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Report", inversedBy="answers")
     */
     private $report;
     ...
}
```

I add the questions manually in my **ReportType** (I know this is not the best aproach but the questions will never change and I'm only interested in the answers.)

```
class ReportAnswersType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('answers', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Room state',
            'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false,
            'choices'  => array('OK' => 'OK', 'NG' => 'NG', 'NP' => 'NP',),
        ))
        ->add('answers', IntegerType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Temperature',
        ))
        ->add('answers', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Is it good?',
            'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false,
            'choices'  => array('YES' => 'YES', 'NO' => 'NO',),
        ))
        ...
    }
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Report::class,
    ));
}
```

What I would like this to do is to generate a Form with 3 questions and insert each of the answers in the database.
But the rendered form only shows the last question (because with each *->add('answers', ...)* I replace the last one added).

I tried different solutions to solve this:

- Following the documentation on [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html), which, consists in adding each answer (with a label of the question) to the Report in the Controller and then rendering the ReportType. The problem about this is that each of my questions have different type (Choice, Text, Integer...) and I don't know how to customize them individually.
- And I also tried to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202875/symfony3-createformbuilder-with-loop-of-add?noredirect=1&lq=1) in my ReportType but it only shows the last question added.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. In the end I followed the instructions on [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).
To make it work I added the fields **question** and **questionType** to my **Answer** entity. And on the **AnswerType.php** I check everytime what type of question it is, and then I create the type of the answer based on that. It looks like this:

```
 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function ($event) {
        $builder = $event->getForm();
        $answer = $event->getData();
        $questionType = $answer->getQuestionType();
        $question = $answer->getQuestion();
        if ($questionType == 1){
            $builder->add('answer', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => $question,
                'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false,
                'choices'  => array('OK' => 'OK', 'NG' => 'NG', 'NP' => 'NP',),
            ));
        }
        else if($questionType == 2){
            $builder->add('answer', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => $question,
                'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false,
                'choices'  => array('SI' => 'SI', 'NO' => 'NO',),
            ));
        }
       else ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Entity–Attribute–Value model to solve this problem. I would suggest using sidus/eav-model-bundle. This would be a great deal of work but you would learn alot. Using EAV model, you can have N number of questions and answers. 
I can not think of solving this using simple form types.